# What is the expected behaviour for relative `newResource` in webpack's `NormalModuleReplacementPlugin`?

Tags: webpack

In the [documentation for webpack's `NormalModuleReplacementPlugin`](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/normal-module-replacement-plugin/) it states:

> If `newResource` is relative, it is resolved relative to the previous resource.

The example in the documentation is:

```js
new webpack.NormalModuleReplacementPlugin(
  /some\/path\/config\.development\.js/,
  './config.production.js'
);
```

This led me to believe that the 'previous resource' is the import matched by the regex and not the resource requesting the import. Is this assumption correct, because it does not seem to work, and the [plugin's code](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/blob/11fa1d514dbf2cbf0db834bf382cce2225ced362/lib/NormalModuleReplacementPlugin.js#L27) suggests it is incorrect, as the path to the matched import is ignored when replacing it.

I have fixed this by passing a function to the plugin, instead of the string, but would like to know if the behaviour observed is expected.

Here is a [link](https://github.com/thomsj/broken-webpack-NormalModuleReplacementPlugin) to a repository to show the error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> 'previous resource' is the import matched by the regex

yes, the related code is [here](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/blob/11fa1d514dbf2cbf0db834bf382cce2225ced362/lib/NormalModuleReplacementPlugin.js#L38-L41)

I created a demo project
https://github.com/loveky/webpack-NormalModuleReplacementPlugin-demo you can download and try

Here is a breakpoint using the demo project.

[image]

---

update based on the broken [repo](https://github.com/thomsj/broken-webpack-NormalModuleReplacementPlugin)

if you change the line in `src/a/b/c/import3.js` from :

```
import { something } from '../../e/initial.js';
```

to

```
import { something } from '../../e/initial';
```

then you should be able to compile without error.

**Why:**

If you import `../../e/initial.js`, then in the beforeResolve hook, the `result.request` has the format of:

```
"../../e/initial.js"
```

which matches your regexp `/\/e\/initial\.js$/`, and then the plugin [updates the request](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/blob/11fa1d514dbf2cbf0db834bf382cce2225ced362/lib/NormalModuleReplacementPlugin.js#L27) and cause a `Module not found` error.

if you import `../../e/initial`, which does not match `/\/e\/initial\.js$/` since it missing the `.js` extension, and that goes to `afterResolve` hook where the path is replaced properly.

So to make it works, we should omit the file extension in our import. This is not documented in the plugins documentation. Maybe you can submit an issue on GitHub to request some clarification from the author.

**Edit:**

If you are on Windows, then the path separator is `\`. so to create a regexp that works on all platform, you can use `path.sep`.

Comment: I looked at the code you linked to before I asked the question. The problem is that the regex is already matched before the resolve (in the link I posted) so the regex would no longer match after the resolve, if it did resolve, which it doesn't, as the path to the module to be replaced is ignored when replacing the module before the resolve.

Comment: I didn't see the reason why the regexp cannot match after the resolve. I have updated the answer with a screenshoot. @JamesT

Comment: I made an edit to include a link to a repository which shows the error.

Comment: Thanks. I'm using Windows, so had to change the regex to `/\\e\\initial\.js$/`. Could you update the answer to mention this?